# Laravel 5.5 - Save multiple data continiously from blade

Tags: laravel, ahp

I want to make a PHP method using laravel. I want to do the comparison of criteria and criteria. Here is the controller code :

```
public function create()
{
 $kriteria1 = Model\Kriteria::pluck('nama_kriteria', 'id');
 $kriteria2 = Model\Kriteria::pluck('nama_kriteria', 'id');
 return view('kriteria_kriterias.create')->with('kriteria1', $kriteria1)->with('kriteria2', $kriteria2)->with('data', $data);
}
```

and this is the blade code :

[image: fields.blade]

It will make the form appear as total of criteria#

The problem is, I can't save it all to database. How do I get it to do this?

Comment: `$data = Model\Kriteria::count();`

Comment: i use that after `$kriteria2 = .....` on `function create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated method in the controller to the following:

```
public function create()
{

    $kriteria1 = Model\Kriteria::pluck('nama_kriteria', 'id');
    $kriteria2 = Model\Kriteria::pluck('nama_kriteria', 'id');

    $data = [
        'kriteria1' => $kriteria1,
        'kriteria2' => $kriteria2
    ];

    return view('kriteria_kriterias.create')->with($data);
}
```

How to output in the blade file:

```
{{ $kriteria1 }}
{{ $kriteria2 }}
```

Or you update the controller to pass the complete results:

```
public function create($id1, $id2)
{

    $kriteria1 = Model\Kriteria::find($id1);
    $kriteria2 = Model\Kriteria::find($id2);

    $data = [
        'kriteria1' => $kriteria1,
        'kriteria2' => $kriteria2
    ];

    return view('kriteria_kriterias.create')->with($data);
}
```

And the in the blade you can accss the data in various ways, one way is a foreach loop using blade in the blade template:

```
@foreach($kriteria1 as $k1)
    {{ $k1 }}
@endforeach

@foreach($kriteria2 as $k2)
    {{ $k2 }}
@endforeach'
```

To accept multiple values dynamicaly in the controller you can try something like this:

```
public function create($ids)
{

    $results = collect([]);

    foreach($ids as $id) {

        $kriteria = Model\Kriteria::findOrFail($id);

        if($kriteria) {
            $results->put('kriteria' . $id, $kriteria);
        }
    }

    return view('kriteria_kriterias.create')->with($results);
}
```

Then use the same looping method mentioned above to display them in the blade or a for loop that gets the count and displays accordingly.

Comment: i will try it ****

Comment: is that will save all automatically

Comment: how if i want to show the comparison like this, example :
`kriteria1 x kriteria1`
`kriteria1 x kriteria2`
`kriteria1 x kriteria3`

`kriteria2 x kriteria2`
`kriteria2 x kriteria3`

`kriteria3 x kriteria3`

Comment: other value/weight set automatically, example `kriteria3 x kriteria1` will set automatically 1/weight we fill on `kriteria1 x kriteria3`

Comment: to save using a model you would use the create() in place of find() method, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Also check out `firstOrCreate()` and `firstOrNew()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to add the opening tag ;)

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
    //put your code in here (line 1-34)
{!! Form::close() !!}
```